# Nodejs how to get child process from process Id

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

Hi any one knows in node JS how to get a child process from a process id?
something like this
Thank you

```
var pid="1212";
var process=getprocess(pid)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately i did n't get any Node JS code for this but i found a solution through following power shell script running as a child process with passing process id as a parameter.

```
$a=Get-WmiObject win32_process | where {$_.ParentProcessId -eq $processid }
```